# Put space between specific strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with R. Below you can see my code and my data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Column = c("0101100000", "2201205000"))
```

[image]

In the column my data is text which is composed of ten characters.

Now I want to put space between first and second four characters. I tried with this line below but is not working.

```
df$Column1 <- gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", df$Column)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to have data frame as data shown in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gsub` like so:

```r
gsub('(.{4})', '\\1 ', df$Column)
#[1] "0101 1000 00" "2201 2050 00"
```

In some cases, this will add a trailing space; use `trimws` in that case:

```r
trimws(gsub('(.{4})', '\\1 ', "02020202"))
#[1] "0202 0202"
```

Answer (score 1):

`read.fwf` (read fixed widths) can be used:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Column1 = Column %>%
    textConnection %>%  
    read.fwf(c(4, 4, 2), colClasses = "character") %>%
    do.call("paste", .))
##       Column      Column1
## 1 0101100000 0101 1000 00
## 2 2201205000 2201 2050 00
```